# how can I download zosRequestLogging-1.0 for liberty from wasdev.net

Tags: websphere-liberty

I tried to download zosRequestLogging-1.0 for liberty from wasdev.net.
here is what I did.

1) click on download
2) search for zosRequestLogging-1.0 
3) wasdev.net shows zosRequestLogging-1.0

there is no download button in the page.

Thanks David

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install the zosRequestLogging-1.0 feature, the easiest thing to do would be just run: 
wlp/bin/installUtility install zosRequestLogging-1.0.

However, if you do want to download it, you can instead do: 
wlp/bin/installUtility download zosRequestLogging-1.0 --location={someLocation, ex: C:\zosRequestLogging}